# Is there a simple way to setup PHP on a website

Tags: php, html

How would you setup PHP on a website including getting it and all? I've tried looking it up, but no site is very helpful. I've tried putting in regular PHP code, but it just comes out like this on the web page:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
   echo "Hello World!";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Including the server

Comment: What is the extention of your file. Is it `.php`?

Comment: Yeah it's ```.php```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your code in a `.php` file which will be run by a Server like apache/nginx. You could install [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) for an easy setup.

Simply install `xampp`, put your code in for example `index.php` and keep that file in xampp/htdocs. If you now run the server locally, you can reach your website by typing http://localhost in the browser.

Comment: sorry where would the html file be?

Comment: your .php file will behave like the .html file but you can use php code in it. So you can basicly put all your html code in the php file mixed with actual php. Just like your given example

Comment: Yes. The server will be able to serve php and html files

Comment: you are weclome :)